# Maintaining optimised referential integrity between 3 table when one table child to another

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have 3 table as follows --

```
 CREATE TABLE countrymaster
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  country character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  currency character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  created_on character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  updated_on character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  idcompany integer NOT NULL,
  iduser integer NOT NULL,
  status status DEFAULT '1'::status,
  CONSTRAINT countrymaster_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT countrymaster_idcompany_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idcompany)
      REFERENCES companies (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT countrymaster_iduser_fkey FOREIGN KEY (iduser)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE regionmaster
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  region_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  region_code character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  created_on character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  updated_on character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  idcountry integer NOT NULL,
  idcompany integer NOT NULL,
  iduser integer NOT NULL,
  status status DEFAULT '1'::status,
  CONSTRAINT regionmaster_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT regionmaster_idcompany_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idcompany)
      REFERENCES companies (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT regionmaster_idcountry_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idcountry)
      REFERENCES countrymaster (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT regionmaster_iduser_fkey FOREIGN KEY (iduser)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE statemaster
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  state_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  created_on character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  updated_on character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  idcountry integer NOT NULL,
  idregion integer,
  idcompany integer NOT NULL,
  iduser integer NOT NULL,
  status status DEFAULT '1'::status,
  CONSTRAINT statemaster_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT statemaster_idcompany_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idcompany)
      REFERENCES companies (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT statemaster_idcountry_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idcountry)
      REFERENCES countrymaster (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT statemaster_idregion_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idregion)
      REFERENCES regionmaster (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT statemaster_iduser_fkey FOREIGN KEY (iduser)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

How can I maintain an optimized referential integrity between three.

Suppose I have a country India. In India have North,South,East,West as region and in north region I have Kashmir,Delhi,Up,Chennai.

Suppose, Now I have to change all region to china.How could I reflect it in "statemaster" table also in a optimized way.

Please suggest any one.How could I handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You've given yourself a problem by putting an FK between country and state. There is no direct relation: the relation are:

1. a state has a region
2. a region has a country

This does imply that a state also has a country but it's not direct - it's via region.

You have in effect denormalised this relationship. To put in proper 3NF you need to get rid of the FK between state and country, and remove the countryId from state. When you want to know about the country a state finds itself in you need to look via the region row it relates to, and then the country row the region is related to.

It is t rue that this seems less efficient, but it does cause problems as you are finding if you don't do it. In practice, denormalisation is only done when inefficiencies grow too large - the system becomes too slow. I have never found this particular type of relation gives a problem requiring denormalisation.

Comment: hello friend I know this structure is not in  a 3NF because we need a system like this.Because in our system a state may or may not be under a region but must be under a country, so I have to put a foreign key with country. Hope you can understand my problem now.

Comment: One way I might do that is to add a 'Not Known' or 'No Region' or whatever region under each country, and then put the states which don't have a region in that region to link them to the country.